# JSF h tags not displaying

Tags: jsf, facelets

Using Netbeans to deploy a web app on Glassfish 3.1.2.2 and none of my h tags display on the web. For instance:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">
    <head>
        <title>Draft Savvy Beers</title>
    </head>
    <h:form>
        <h:body>
            <h1>Search for beers</h1>
            <p><strong>Would you like to search for a beer?</strong>
                <h:inputText value="#{draftSavvyController.searchTerm}" />
                <h:commandButton value="#{draftSavvyController.searchforBeers}" /></p>
        </h:body>
    </h:form>
</html>
```

displays only the text, no input field or button. Using plain old html shows the fields and buttons obviously, but I can't access my controller this way. Here is my web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
        <param-value>Development</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.DEFAULT_SUFFIX</param-name>
    <param-value>.xhtml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>login.xhtml</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

Let me know if I can provide anymore info. I'm pretty new at this...

Comment: I hope you're adding the correct jsf related libraries in your CLASSPATH?

Comment: @HashimR I added the JSF 2.1 jars (api and impl) to my project. Do I also need to add them to my CLASSPATH environment variable?

Comment: Your new problem with the exception is completely unrelated to the initial question. You should be asking a separeate quesiton for that instead of chameleonizing an existing question for that.

Comment: I guess I don't understand servlets enough to even know what question to ask here.

Comment: Just put your managed bean code and stack trace in your question. no worries :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11789847/jsf-2-x-ejb-dependency-injection-error

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Add this to your `web.xml`:

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

I think the cause of the problem is that the request is not being passed through the FacesServlet.

The page URL did not match the url-pattern of the FacesServlet, thus it had not any chance to parse the tags.

Comment: I'm getting an error now. Stack trace is very long but this is the error:  "An error occurred performing resource injection on managed bean draftSavvyController"

Comment: Paste your faces-config.xml in your question.

Comment: I took out the *xhtml url-pattern element, and I'm not getting that resource injection error anymore. Still not getting my h tags to display though...

Comment: here's the weird thing: I don't have one. I have another web app that deployed just fine without one, so I didn't think I needed it.

Comment: Ok paste your managed bean code then.

Comment: see above. There are getters and setters below the code that I left off. Thanks for your help so far!

Comment: Please add that `*.xhtml` pattern in `web.xml`. And add the stack trace to your question. Thanks.

Comment: It's underneath my managed bean code.

Comment: While this indeed solves the initial problem, is it *absolutely necessary* to add that much of URL patterns? This is plain clumsy. Just stick to one. Further, I'd be nice if you explain in detail what exactly OP's concrete problem is and how exactly those mappings solves it. Given the fact that he removed `*.xhtml` afterwards, he does not understand your answer at all.

Comment: The problem is with the draftSavyBean. You can't just inject your EJB into the ManagedBean using @EJB.

Comment: @airowe: Your initial problem was that request was not passing through the Faces servlet because you didn't add this servlet mapping in your `web.xml`. As BalusC have mentioned you can ask a separate question for your next problem. Hope you understand. Thanks!

Comment: And it would be nice if you remove managed bean code and stacktrace from your answer :)

Comment: @BalusC so I only need the .xhtml URL pattern to pass through the servlet? My new issue is foreign to me. Not even sure what question to ask.

Comment: Check my updated answer. :) sorry for not explaining it earlier!

Comment: @HashimR I don't understand what you mean when you say "you can't just inject your EJB into the ManagedBean using @EJB." Why can I not use annotation to inject the EJB into the managed bean?

Comment: Can you please ask a separate question? Just paste your managed bean code and stack trace. It would be really nice. Thanks :)

Comment: @airowe: What i meant is that you cannot use `@EJB` annotation inside a jsf 2.x managed bean.