# JSF 2.x @EJB Dependency Injection Error

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee, jsf-2

So, as it usually goes in programming, I asked one question and a potential solution led to more questions (and bugs.) I'm new to using servlets, JSF, and EJBs and have run into an error with dependency injection.

Here's my original question: [JSF h tags not displaying](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11788786/jsf-h-tags-not-displaying)

I was told I needed to ask a new question, pasting my managed bean code and the stack trace that resulted from the injection error. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

ManagedBean

```
@ManagedBean(name ="draftSavvyController")
@RequestScoped
public class DraftSavvyController 
{
    // ======================================
    // =             Attributes             =
    // ======================================
    @EJB
    private DraftSavvyBean draftBean;
    private Person person;
    private String name;
    private String password;
    private String userType;
    private String searchTerm;
    private static final String apiKey = "4765b95b1bb4ca5248261b7b9af443db";

    // ======================================
    // =           Public Methods           =
    // ======================================
    public String doRegisterUser()
    {
        draftBean.registerUser(name, password, userType);
        return "chooseBeers.xhtml";
    }

    public String doCheckForUser()
    {        
        if(draftBean.checkForUser(name, password))
        {
            return "chooseBeers.xhtml";
        }
        else return "loginerror.xhtml";
    }

    public String searchForBeers() throws MalformedURLException, IOException, JSONException
    {
        draftBean.searchForBeers(searchTerm, apiKey);

        return "displaybeers.js";
    }
```

Stack Trace

```
com.sun.faces.mgbean.ManagedBeanCreationException: An error occurred performing resource injection on managed bean draftSavvyController
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanBuilder.injectResources(BeanBuilder.java:211)
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanBuilder.build(BeanBuilder.java:103)
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanManager.createAndPush(BeanManager.java:409)
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanManager.create(BeanManager.java:269)
    at com.sun.faces.el.ManagedBeanELResolver.resolveBean(ManagedBeanELResolver.java:244)
    at com.sun.faces.el.ManagedBeanELResolver.getValue(ManagedBeanELResolver.java:116)
    at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver._getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:176)
    at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver.getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:203)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstIdentifier.getValue(AstIdentifier.java:103)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:179)
    at com.sun.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:224)
    at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldValueExpression.getValue(WeldValueExpression.java:50)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:109)
    at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:194)
    at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:182)
    at javax.faces.component.UIOutput.getValue(UIOutput.java:169)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicInputRenderer.getValue(HtmlBasicInputRenderer.java:205)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicRenderer.getCurrentValue(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:355)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicRenderer.encodeEnd(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:164)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:875)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1764)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1760)
    at javax.faces.render.Renderer.encodeChildren(Renderer.java:168)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:845)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1757)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1760)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:402)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:131)
    at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:288)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:121)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:594)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1550)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:281)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:655)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:595)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:161)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:331)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:231)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$AdapterCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:317)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:195)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:860)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:757)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1056)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:229)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
    at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: com.sun.faces.spi.InjectionProviderException: com.sun.enterprise.container.common.spi.util.InjectionException: Exception attempting to inject Remote ejb-ref name=com.draftsavvy.frontend.DraftSavvyController/draftBean,Remote 3.x interface =com.draftsavvy.frontend.DraftSavvyBean,ejb-link=null,lookup=,mappedName=,jndi-name=com.draftsavvy.frontend.DraftSavvyBean,refType=Session into class com.draftsavvy.frontend.DraftSavvyController: Lookup failed for 'java:comp/env/com.draftsavvy.frontend.DraftSavvyController/draftBean' in SerialContext[myEnv={java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialInitContextFactory, java.naming.factory.state=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl, java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.sun.enterprise.naming}
    at org.glassfish.faces.integration.GlassFishInjectionProvider.inject(GlassFishInjectionProvider.java:194)
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanBuilder.injectResources(BeanBuilder.java:205)
    ... 56 more
Caused by: com.sun.enterprise.container.common.spi.util.InjectionException: Exception attempting to inject Remote ejb-ref name=com.draftsavvy.frontend.DraftSavvyController/draftBean,Remote 3.x interface =com.draftsavvy.frontend.DraftSavvyBean,ejb-link=null,lookup=,mappedName=,jndi-name=com.draftsavvy.frontend.DraftSavvyBean,refType=Session into class com.draftsavvy.frontend.DraftSavvyController: Lookup failed for 'java:comp/env/com.draftsavvy.frontend.DraftSavvyController/draftBean' in SerialContext[myEnv={java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialInitContextFactory, java.naming.factory.state=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl, java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.sun.enterprise.naming}
    at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.util.InjectionManagerImpl._inject(InjectionManagerImpl.java:703)
    at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.util.InjectionManagerImpl.inject(InjectionManagerImpl.java:470)
    at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.util.InjectionManagerImpl.injectInstance(InjectionManagerImpl.java:171)
    at org.glassfish.faces.integration.GlassFishInjectionProvider.inject(GlassFishInjectionProvider.java:184)
    ... 57 more
Caused by: javax.naming.NamingException: Lookup failed for 'java:comp/env/com.draftsavvy.frontend.DraftSavvyController/draftBean' in SerialContext[myEnv={java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialInitContextFactory, java.naming.factory.state=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl, java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.sun.enterprise.naming} [Root exception is javax.naming.NamingException: Exception resolving Ejb for 'Remote ejb-ref name=com.draftsavvy.frontend.DraftSavvyController/draftBean,Remote 3.x interface =com.draftsavvy.frontend.DraftSavvyBean,ejb-link=null,lookup=,mappedName=,jndi-name=com.draftsavvy.frontend.DraftSavvyBean,refType=Session' .  Actual (possibly internal) Remote JNDI name used for lookup is 'com.draftsavvy.frontend.DraftSavvyBean#com.draftsavvy.frontend.DraftSavvyBean' [Root exception is javax.naming.NamingException: Lookup failed for 'com.draftsavvy.frontend.DraftSavvyBean#com.draftsavvy.frontend.DraftSavvyBean' in SerialContext[myEnv={java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialInitContextFactory, java.naming.factory.state=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl, java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.sun.enterprise.naming} [Root exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: com.draftsavvy.frontend.DraftSavvyBean#com.draftsavvy.frontend.DraftSavvyBean not found]]]
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:518)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:455)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:392)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:392)
    at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.util.InjectionManagerImpl._inject(InjectionManagerImpl.java:599)
    ... 60 more
Caused by: javax.naming.NamingException: Exception resolving Ejb for 'Remote ejb-ref name=com.draftsavvy.frontend.DraftSavvyController/draftBean,Remote 3.x interface =com.draftsavvy.frontend.DraftSavvyBean,ejb-link=null,lookup=,mappedName=,jndi-name=com.draftsavvy.frontend.DraftSavvyBean,refType=Session' .  Actual (possibly internal) Remote JNDI name used for lookup is 'com.draftsavvy.frontend.DraftSavvyBean#com.draftsavvy.frontend.DraftSavvyBean' [Root exception is javax.naming.NamingException: Lookup failed for 'com.draftsavvy.frontend.DraftSavvyBean#com.draftsavvy.frontend.DraftSavvyBean' in SerialContext[myEnv={java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialInitContextFactory, java.naming.factory.state=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl, java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.sun.enterprise.naming} [Root exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: com.draftsavvy.frontend.DraftSavvyBean#com.draftsavvy.frontend.DraftSavvyBean not found]]
    at com.sun.ejb.EjbNamingReferenceManagerImpl.resolveEjbReference(EjbNamingReferenceManagerImpl.java:191)
    at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.ComponentEnvManagerImpl$EjbReferenceProxy.create(ComponentEnvManagerImpl.java:1109)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.GlassfishNamingManagerImpl.lookup(GlassfishNamingManagerImpl.java:776)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.GlassfishNamingManagerImpl.lookup(GlassfishNamingManagerImpl.java:744)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.JavaURLContext.lookup(JavaURLContext.java:169)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:498)
    ... 64 more
Caused by: javax.naming.NamingException: Lookup failed for 'com.draftsavvy.frontend.DraftSavvyBean#com.draftsavvy.frontend.DraftSavvyBean' in SerialContext[myEnv={java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialInitContextFactory, java.naming.factory.state=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl, java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.sun.enterprise.naming} [Root exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: com.draftsavvy.frontend.DraftSavvyBean#com.draftsavvy.frontend.DraftSavvyBean not found]
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:518)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:455)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:392)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:392)
    at com.sun.ejb.EjbNamingReferenceManagerImpl.resolveEjbReference(EjbNamingReferenceManagerImpl.java:186)
    ... 69 more
Caused by: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: com.draftsavvy.frontend.DraftSavvyBean#com.draftsavvy.frontend.DraftSavvyBean not found
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.TransientContext.doLookup(TransientContext.java:248)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.TransientContext.lookup(TransientContext.java:215)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContextProviderImpl.lookup(SerialContextProviderImpl.java:77)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.LocalSerialContextProviderImpl.lookup(LocalSerialContextProviderImpl.java:119)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:505)
    ... 73 more
```

Stateless Bean

```
@Stateless
public class DraftSavvyBean implements DraftSavvyBeanRemote {

    // ======================================
    // =             Attributes             =
    // ======================================

    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "DraftSavvyFrontEndPU")
    private EntityManager em;

    // ======================================
    // =           Public Methods           =
    // ======================================
    public void registerUser(String username, String password, String userType)
    {
        //code here
    }

    public boolean checkForUser(String username, String password)
    {
        //code here
    } 

    public void searchForBeers(String searchTerm, String apiKey) throws MalformedURLException, IOException, JSONException
    {
        //code here
    }

}
```

Comment: How is your DraftSavvyBean look like?

Comment: @PetrMensik added above.

Comment: And why is your EJB remote?Try to make it Local to see if it works (and if everything is running on one server then there is no need to have remote beans)

Comment: @airowe: This [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6905186/injection-of-ejb3-into-annotation-based-jsf2-backing-bean-causing-javax-naming-n?answertab=votes#tab-top) might be helpful. Try it and tell me if its working :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Petr Mensik said, you probably don't need a remote EJB (unless you plan to call methods of that ejb from a different server). You can use a `@Local` interface, or even not interface at all. just declare the bean @Stateless and remove the `implements DraftSavvyBeanRemote` .

If you do use an interface (either local or remote) you have to inject a reference to the interface, not to the bean. So your inject should look like this.

```
@EJB
private DraftSavvyBeanRemote draftBean;
```

Comment: Thank you Damian and @Petr Mensik. That makes perfect sense. This is the first time I was tying two projects (a back end and front end) together and was under the impression I needed the remote ejb to have them communicate.