# Didn't show jsf code

Tags: jsf

i instailled jars: javax.faces 2.1.14 and javax.servlet:jstl:1.1.0. My idea see that is jsf, but when it shows in tomcat it can't it recognize. 
[First img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nCNaJ.png)

[Second img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uhHxe.png)

Comment: refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11788786/jsf-h-tags-not-displaying

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to install the implementation of jsf, like mojarra or my-faces, not only API library. Have checked log to see if some error is present?

Comment: Now i have got error 404.

Comment: Type Status Report

Description The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists.Type Status Report

Description The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists.